# Large space between image other tag with itext7

Tags: html2pdf, itext7

There is a large space between the image and other tag in the pdf.Here are two cases, image-text and image-image.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <!--============image-text==============-->
    <li>コマンド <em>net view \\virtualhostname を入力します。<br></em>メッセージ
        "<em>アクセスが拒否されました</em>" が表示される場合は、レジストリキーが適切に設定されていないか、または Windows OS
        を再起動する必要があります。<br>
    <img alt="ScreenShot005.png" height="312"
        src="./images/ScreenShot005.png" title="ScreenShot005.png"
        width="437"></li>
    <li>他のサーバからコマンド <em>net view \\virtualhostname</em> を使用します。<br>エラー
        "<em>ネットワーク上に同じ名前があります</em>" が表示される場合は、キー <em>DisableStrictNameChecking</em>
        が適切に設定されていません。
    </li>
    <li>MMC を使用して、コンピュータ <em>virtualhostname</em> に接続します。
        <ol start="1" style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
            <li><em>SAP MMC</em> を開きます。</li>
            <li>"<em>ファイル</em> –&gt; <em>スナップインの追加と削除</em>" を選択します。
            </li>
            <li>"<em>コンピュータの管理</em>" を選択し、"<em>追加</em>" をクリックします。
            </li>
            <li>"<em>OK</em>" をクリックします。<br>
            <!--============image-image==============-->
            <img alt="ScreenShot006.png" height="700" src="./images/ScreenShot006.png"
                title="ScreenShot006.png" width="936"><br>
            <br>
            <img alt="ScreenShot007.png" height="363"
                src="./images/ScreenShot007.png" title="ScreenShot007.png"
                width="934"></li>
        </ol></li>
</ul>
```

PDF result:
 1. [image: image-text]
 2. [image: image-image]

Comment: whats the output?

Comment: The sreenshot files are cropped properly? They don't contain any transparent blank or plain white space below the image? It looks like pdfHTML tried to fit the next image on the first page but found through its calculations that it wouldn't fit and moved it to the next page.

Comment: Also, does the same behavior occur when the images are not wrapped in the list? And is a seperate CSS file present (or other CSS statements in the html)

Comment: it's cropped properly.It happens in the block tag.like 
<li><img src="..."> </li>
<p><img src="..."></p>

Comment: Replaced the screenshots with my own placeholder images and converted it myself. Everything's on one page for me. Well, not really on, since the images are too wide and large to fit on default A.4. What page-size are you using? Also, try adding borders to the image and li elements, to see how much space they take up.

Comment: This question is currently being tracked in iText JIRA with issue id TSALES-1537, we will reply via email.